# Есть два инпута текстбокса, нужно в третью выводить их значение

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Прошу вас дайте мне совет или подсказку, я то не как не могу разобраться что к чему, потому что впервые сталкиваюсь 
Вообщем есть 3 `input type=textbox`. После того как в две `input`- а вводиться значение, в третью должна появиться сумма этих двух `input`- ов. 
Какое событие поставить в третьего `input` или в второго `input`??? 
И `java` или `jquery` нужно в этом использовать?
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Где у вас находится контроллер?

Comment: В php+xampp находиться страница, где в будущем будет обрабатываться значения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JQuery использовать необязательно

```js
function changeInputs() {
  let input1 = +document.getElementById("input_1").value || 0;
  let input2 = +document.getElementById("input_2").value || 0;
  document.getElementById("input_3").value = input1 + input2;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input_1" oninput="changeInputs()">1 input</input>
</br>
<input type="number" id="input_2" oninput="changeInputs()">2 input</input>
</br>
<input type="number" id="input_3">3 input</input>
```

Comment: Событие `keyup` лучше заменить на другое. Например, на `input`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Спасибо, вы правы, сделал)))

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, именно то что я себе представляла...)))

Comment: @Zolushka Рад помочь. Обращайтесь))